# What changed in Linux kernel (2.6.22) that gives hdparm support for power-on in standby?

Tags: hard-disk, linux-kernel, power-management, sata

Hdparm man page lists for parameter `-s`:

> Enable/disable the power-on in standby feature, if supported by
>                 the drive.  VERY DANGEROUS.  Do not use  unless  you  are  abso-
>                 lutely  certain  that both the system BIOS (or firmware) and the
>                 operating system kernel (Linux >= 2.6.22)  support  probing  for
>                 drives  that  use this feature.

Could you point to a commit or lines in source code that gives the support for "power-on in standby".

In other words what is the change in Linux kernel (2.6.22) that made PUIS/POIS possible?

Answer (score 1):

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/ata/libata-core.c?v=3.5#L1987

The code makes a call to `ata_dev_set_feature(dev, SETFEATURES_SPINUP, 0);`